# how can i change the froala editor default image width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

according to [this page](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options#imageDefaultWidth) i should replacing 300px with 0 to disable adding inline style width to the uploaded image in my froala editor.

i should adding this code to the some place but , i dont know what should i do ?

```
$('.selector').froalaEditor({
  imageDefaultWidth: 200
});
```

i try  ../flora/plugins/image.min.js but  it doesn't work for me , and still i have inline style in my source code

Answer (score 0):

I think you may already found you answer by now but in case if anybody else face the same problem the below code might help them.

```
 <script>   
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            try
            {
                $(function()
                {
                    $('#description').froalaEditor({
                        heightMin: 500,
                        width: '100%'


                    })
                });
            }catch(err) {}
        });
    </script>
```